# cannot find protocol declaration for UITabBarControllerDelegate

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode6, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to implement a TabBarDelegate but I'm getting this error:

```
cannot find protocol declaration for UITabBarControllerDelegate
```

I add an NSObject class:

```
@interface tabBarDelegate : NSObject <UITabBarControllerDelegate>
```

any of you knows why I'm getting this error? or how resolve this error?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you remember to `@import UIKit;`?

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that a declaration couldn't be found for the protocol `UITabBarControllerDelegate`.

So solve this, you need to be sure to import UIKit (the framework in which the protocol is declared).

```
@import UIKit;
```

Or, if all you need to access from UIKit in this file is the `UITabBarControllerDelegate`, you have the option of only importing `UITabBarController`'s declarations.

```
@import UIKit.UITabBarController;
```